# Docker compose errors using volumes

Tags: python, django, docker

Here's the deal:

1. I want to create an image based on python:latest, for Django development.
2. I want to create the Django project INSIDE THE CONTAINER and make it reflect on a host folder, via docker volumes.
3. I want to use the python interpreter from the container for development.

   This way, I can have only my Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and requirements.txt on my project folder, not depending on Python, virtualenvs or anything like that on my host.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:latest
ARG requirements=requirements/production.txt
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r $requirements && \
    django-admin startproject myproject .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        requirements: requirements/development.txt
    networks:
      - main
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app:rw"
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    networks:
      - main
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  main:
```

The main issue are the volumes in web. If I build the image via `docker build -t somename:sometag .` the build works fine. If I run `docker run -it my_image bash` it shows me all the files created inside /app.

But if I try `docker-compose up` it fails the web part, saying that could not find manage.py, and exiting with code 2. Only Postgres is running after that.

So, finally, my questions are:

This kind of workflow is possible? Is it the best option, since it does not depend on Python on the host?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what would happen if you remove the `volume` part from docker-compose? (I did the same with `mysql`)

Comment: Try to use absolute path in `CMD`.

Comment: Isn't the manage.py located outside the app directory on the host?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge : It works but kills the purpose of my compose file.

@Sraw : same error as always: `can't open file '/app/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` (building the image with docker build works and the file is there)

@Shoan: no, it's inside app folder

Comment: We use a very similar setup and it works fine. The difference is that we specify the command in the `docker-compose.yml` rather than `CMD` in the DockerFile itself. What happens if you remove the `CMD` from the DockerFile, and add `command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` to your `docker-compose.yml` ?

Comment: @WillKeeling, same result, `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. The funny thing is that all files are created in a simple docker build